# php my admin one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, phpmyadmin, admin

I'm using mySQL and PHPMyAdmin.

I have the floowing three tables and fields in my DB;

```
T_users;
F_uID - varchar - (PK)
F_Forename - text
F_Surname - text

T_candidates;
F_bookingRef - int - auto increment - (PK)
F_sessionID - int
F_uID - varchar

T_TrainingSessions;
F_sessionID - int - auto increment - (PK)
F_sessionDesc - text
F_sessionDate - date
```

I would like to create a one-to-many relationship between T_Users.F_uID and T_candidates.F_Uid.

I would also like to create a one-to-many relationship between T_TrainingSessions.F_sessionID and T_candidates.F_sessionID.

However, when I click on 'relation view' in any of the table structure sections in PHPMyAdmin I can only select fields that are primary keys from the drop down lists!

From my reading, i think this may have something to do with indexes, however I have no knowledge or experience of setting indexes.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

:)

Tim

Comment: What engine are you using? Example: InnoDB, MyISAM

Answer (score 1):

You can make foreign keys from fields that are primary keys or fields that have unique values.

If you can't create the relations

```
T_Users.F_uID<---->>T_candidates.F_Uid
T_TrainingSessions.F_sessionID<---->>T_candidates.F_sessionID 
(one<---->>many)
```

maybe you are trying to create the inverse relations.

try this:

```
CREATE TABLE T_users (
  F_uID VARCHAR(SIZE) NOT NULL,
  F_Forename TEXT NOT NULL,
  F_Surname TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(F_uID)
)
TYPE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE T_TrainingSessions (
  F_sessionID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  F_sessionDesc TEXT NOT NULL,
  F_sessionDate DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(F_sessionID)
)
TYPE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE T_candidates (
  F_bookingRef INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  F_sessionID INT NOT NULL,
  F_uID VARCHAR(SIZE) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(F_bookingRef)
  INDEX FKIndex1(F_sessionID),
  INDEX FKIndex2(F_uID),
  FOREIGN KEY(F_uID)
    REFERENCES T_users(F_uID)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  FOREIGN KEY(F_sessionID)
    REFERENCES T_TrainingSessions(F_sessionID)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
TYPE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Hi, Yes - T_Users.F_uID will always be unique, as will T_TrainingSessions.F_sessionID. T_candidates.F_Uid and T_candidates.F_sessionID may contain many duplicates. Could you talk me through the process you would go through if it's not too much trouble? :)

Comment: Have you set the foreign key fields as unique in phpmyadmin?  When you view the structure of a table the fields are displayed and under the action column there are several icons.  There should be an icon that looks like a table with a U in it.  Make sure this has been set for the foreign key fields.

Comment: Hi, I can see the icon you're referring to. Just to clarify, you're saying I should set T_candidates.F_Uid and T_candidates.F_sessionID as unique. These fields do not hold unique data - will this cause a problem or am I missing something?

Comment: see my edited post, try with this script, I'm not sure if i have some sintax errors (I wrote the script in text editor).